# How to: Get correct mouse down event on a SVG within clipped area

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I would like to get mousedown trigger only when the mouse points within clip path of a svg. If there are two svgs, with visible parts, pointing on the visual part will result triggering an event with a target that defined the clicked visible part. How can I do that correctly?

I wrote a case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roni45/uaHLP/1/#&togetherjs=ATHzTyQORV) that demonstrate my problem. It working well for me in IE, but not in Chrome. In Chrome, clicking & dragging the red part work OK. Clicking and dragging the green part will not work, unless the red object (not only the visible path) will not share any area of the green object.

html code:

```
<body>
    <p> clicked object: </p> <button id="test" >id</button>
    <svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg1" 
         style="clip-path: url('#clip1'); position:fixed; left:100px; top: 100px; ">
        <g>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip1" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:3; fill: none;">
                    <path d="M0 0 l 400 0 l 0 400 Z"></path>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="green" style="clip-path: url('#clip1'); " id="green1"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2"
         style="clip-path: url('#clip2'); position:fixed; left:100px; top: 100px; ">
        <g >
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip2" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:3; fill: none;">
                    <path d="M0 0 l 400 400 l -400 0 Z"></path>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="red" style="clip-path: url('#clip2'); " id="red"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
        var zvalmax = 2;
        $("[id^='svg']").draggable({
            scroll: false,
            start: function (e) {
                $(this).css("z-index", ++zvalmax);
            },
            stop: function (e) {
            }
        });
        document.onmousedown = who
        function who(e) {
            var id = e.target.id;
            $("#test").html(id);
        }

    </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a workaround like this:

```
svg { pointer-events: none; }
svg * { pointer-events: all; }
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EB6x/).

Note that according to [SVG 1.1 Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#hit-testing) whether the svg root itself can be a direct target for mouse events is explicitly undefined:

> This specification does not define the behavior of pointer events on
>   the rootmost ‘svg’ element for SVG images which are embedded by
>   reference or inclusion within another document, e.g., whether the
>   rootmost ‘svg’ element embedded in an HTML document intercepts mouse
>   click events; future specifications may define this behavior, but for
>   the purpose of this specification, the behavior is
>   implementation-specific.

This has not yet been resolved in SVG2.