# Meteor not recognizing svg events (mousedown)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, meteor

I am trying to create a workflow diagram using the d3 package and meteor. Nodes can be added by clicking on the page, and edges can be drawn from one node to another. However, when I click on the page, meteor does not recognize the mousedown event. Here is the code I am using in the event handler:

```
Template.graph.events({ 
  'mousedown svg': function (event,tmpl) {
     d3.event.preventDefault();
     console.log("mousedown");
     svg.classed('active', true);
     if(d3.event.ctrlKey || mousedown_node || mousedown_link) return;
     var point = d3.mouse(this),
     node = {id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false};
     node.x = point[0];
     node.y = point[1];
     nodes.push(node);
     restart();
  }
});
```

And this is how I have set up my svg:

```
var width  = 800,
height = 300,
colors = d3.scale.category10();
var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height);
```

I have tried using other solutions like (where mousedown is the above function):

```
svg.on('mousedown',mousedown);
```

However, i get errors such as "Cannot read property preventDefault of null". My assumption is that meteor is not storing the event. I have tried using another variable to store the event, and run operations on that variable, but to no effect.
For example:

```
svg.on('mousedown',function(event){
    var evt=event;
    mousedown(event);
});
```

How would I get meteor to recognize the mousedown event on svg?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Meteor issue and not an SVG issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582198/how-to-get-correct-mouse-down-event-on-a-svg-within-clipped-area

Comment: D3 events aren't really normal Javascript events and you can't mix the handlers for them. I'd use a D3 event handler in this case.

Comment: I tried using the .on method but ended up with the same error